# can any one explain reduce function in javascripts

Tags: javascript

Can any one explain whats going on in this JavaScript code? I do not understand the part where the `i.reduce` is passed with `[]` as an initial value:

```
function longestString(i) {
    // It will be an array like (['big',[0,1,2,3,4],'tiny'])
    // and the function should return the longest string in the array

    // This should flatten an array of arrays
    var r = i.reduce(function(a, b) {
        return a.concat(b);
    }, []);

    // This should fetch the longest in the flattened array
    return r.reduce(function (a, b) 
    { 
        return a.length > b.length ? a : b; 
    });
}
```

Comment: I cleaned up your question as best I could, but I'm still not sure what you are asking. Are you asking "why" `[]` is passed? Or what it does? Or looking for the docs on [`Array.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)?

Comment: Does it not work? is there anything wrong with the output? If not, Google is a more appropriate place to ask ["how it works"](https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+reduce) because [the first result](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) has an informative description of the function.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fold_(higher-order_function)

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce#Syntax

Comment: i was asking whats  the use of passing [] as a parameter

Answer (score 2):

The initial value in a reduce is an accumulator.  If for example if i is `[[1],[2],[3]]` then the reduce statement is equivalent to:

```
r = [];
r = r.concat([1]);
r = r.concat([2]);
r = r.concat([3]);
```

In each step of the reduce the function must be called on two arguments.  In the first step there must be some initial value.  You can't call .concat on nothing so you start with an empty array.

Comment: Just to clarify, if the initial value is provided, `reduce` starts at index `0`. If it isn't, it starts at index `1`, using index `0` as the initial value.